# SwiftUI TabView PageTabViewStyle prevent changing tab?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a `TabView` in SwiftUI in the `PageViewTabStyle` so i can swipe from page to page. I'd like to have a setting that "locks" the current view in place, so the user cannot swipe. Googling and reading docs isn't turning up anything obvious for me, so I was hoping the gurus on SO could help me out.

In short, my code looks like

```
TabView {
   ForEach(0..<5) { idx in
      Text("Cell: \(idx)")
   }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

I have found the `disabled` property, but then it appears that all tap events are ignored on the entire view - I just want to prevent the user from switching tabs (or, in this particular case, swiping or pressing the page dots to switch pages). I've tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168014/swiftui-2-0-tabview-disable-swipe-to-change-page) where the `gesture` property is set to `nil`, but that doesn't appear to actually stop the swipe gesture from changing the page (the `indexDisplayMode` bit was nice, though!)

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: See below - the above `gesture` solution works! However, when there is a subview with eg `onTapGesture`, the subview still intercepts the swipe to change page. I'd like to have subviews that allow touch interaction :)

Comment: What do you mean by subview? In a ZStack? For the code as-is, the `Text` elements don't have any subviews so you'd need to add the blocking gesture to other superviews as well

Answer (score 18):

The solution from mentioned reference works, just the swipe is blocked not by `gesture(nil)`, but by `gesture(DragGesture())`. And view should be full-tab-content-view-wide, like

```
    TabView {
      ForEach(0..<5) { idx in
        Text("Cell: \(idx)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .gesture(DragGesture())      // this blocks swipe
      }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

* *and, of course, it can be made conditional as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63170431/12299030*

Comment: I see - If i have a subview with an `onTapGesture` property, that subview still allows swipe-to-change-pages.

```
    GeometryReader { geom in
      TabView {
        ForEach(0..<5) { idx in
          HStack {
            Text("Cell: \(idx)")
              .onTapGesture { print ("TAP!") } // !!!
              .border(Color.green)
          }
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .contentShape(Rectangle())
          .gesture(DragGesture())      // this blocks swipe
        }
      }
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
```

Comment: ugh, sorry for the formatting there, I'm not sure how to best reply with a chunk of code in comments. The point was, the subview with the `onTapGesture` still swipes to change the page - what's the best (if any) way to disable _that_ ? Thanks!

Comment: haven't tested this, but does it work if you change `.gesture(DragGesture())` to `.simulataneousGesture(DragGesture())`?

Comment: If either of you want to make an answer with simultaneousGesture, I can accept it. Does that allocate the bounty? I'm not sure how that works...

Comment: This doesn't seem to reliably disable two-finger swipe gestures for me.

Answer (score 9):

To block all the swipe gestures in a TabView you have to use `.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture())` that blocks all the swipe gestures in the subviews as well

```
TabView {
          ForEach(0..<5) { idx in
            Text("Cell: \(idx)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture())
          }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

Comment: This also doesn't seem to reliably disable two-finger swipe gestures for me.

Comment: Has anyone been able to figure out a way to get two-finger drag gestures to not break this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is this one. It disables changing tabs by swiping and it keeps the drag gestures enabled on screens as I'm using `List .onDelete` on certain screens.

It is available only from iOS 16

```
@State private var selectedTab = 1

TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    Text("Tab 1")
        .tag(0)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    Text("Tab 2")
        .tag(1)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    Text("Tab 3")
        .tag(2)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
}
```

Comment: You lose that animation of page change with this approach.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, though it is unfortunate that you lose the page change animation.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to roll my own solution using some reflection. It supports both `if` statements (conditional views) and `ForEach` views as well as using the `.tag()` modifier for identification.

```swift
private enum PagingTransition {
    case next, previous
    var value: AnyTransition {
        switch self {
        case .next:
            return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
        case .previous:
            return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
}

private func isOptional(_ instance: Any) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance)
    let style = mirror.displayStyle
    return style == .optional
}

/// Erases generics to get views out of `ForEach`
fileprivate protocol ViewGeneratable {
    func generateViews() -> [any View]
}

extension ForEach: ViewGeneratable {
    func generateViews() -> [any View] {
        self.data.map { self.content($0) as! any View }
    }
}

/// A paging `TabView` replacement that doesn't allow for the user to interact
/// Follows SwiftUI calling conventions as best as possible with dirty reflection
/// https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/inspecting-views/
struct RestrictedPagingView<SelectionType: Hashable & Comparable, Content: View>: View {
    let selection: SelectionType
    @State private var selectionInternal: SelectionType
    @State private var transition: AnyTransition = PagingTransition.next.value
    private var views: [SelectionType: any View] = [:]
    
    init(selection: SelectionType, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.selection = selection
        self._selectionInternal = State(initialValue: selection)
        
        // Attempt reflection
        generateViews(from: content(), withBaseTag: selection)
    }
    
    /// This is the most big brain shit I've coded in a long time
    /// Reflects SwiftUI views and puts them in a dictionary to use within the paging view
    private mutating func generateViews(from instance: Any, withBaseTag baseTag: SelectionType) {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: instance)
        
        // Is this a tuple view?
        if let value = mirror.descendant("value") {
            // Yes, so call this function recusrively until it isn't
            let count = Mirror(reflecting: value).children.count
            for i in 0..<count {
                generateViews(from: mirror.descendant("value", ".\(i)")!, withBaseTag: baseTag)
            }
        } else if isOptional(instance) {
            // This is an Optional, so check if it has a value
            if let child = mirror.children.first?.value {
                // It does, send it back through the function
                generateViews(from: child, withBaseTag: baseTag)
            }
        } else if let content = mirror.descendant("content") {
            // This is a ForEach loop, so unwrap and deal with all views separately
            if mirror.descendant("contentID") != nil {
                for view in (instance as! ViewGeneratable).generateViews() {
                    generateViews(from: view, withBaseTag: baseTag)
                }
                return
            }
            // This is a tagged view, extract the tag and the content and put them in the dictionary
            let tag: SelectionType = mirror.descendant("modifier", "value", "tagged") as! SelectionType

            views[tag] = (content as! any View)
        } else {
            // Just insert the view with a baseline tag
            views[baseTag] = (instance as! any View)
        }
    }
    
    // TODO: Handle removed conditional views more gracefully
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(views.keys.sorted(by: >), id: \.self) { idx in
            if idx == selectionInternal {
                AnyView(views[idx]!)
                    .transition(transition)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selection) { newSelection in
            if newSelection > selectionInternal {
                transition = PagingTransition.next.value
            } else {
                transition = PagingTransition.previous.value
            }
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)) {
                selectionInternal = newSelection
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct RestrictedPagingViewPreview: View {
    @State private var index = 1
    @State private var allow = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RestrictedPagingView(selection: index) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("Hi")
                }.tag(1)
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green)
                    Text("Second")
                }.tag(2)
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text("Third")
                }.tag(3)
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    Button("FOURTH") {
                        print("button activated")
                    }
                }.tag(4)
                if allow {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.orange)
                        Text("Should be hidden (5)")
                    }.tag(5)

                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.purple)
                        Text("Should be hidden (6)")
                    }.tag(6)
                }
                ForEach(7..<11, id: \.self) { tagVal in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.cyan)
                        Text("This view is generated by a ForEach loop! (\(tagVal))")
                    }
                    .tag(tagVal)
                }
            }
            .border(Color.green)
            Button("INCR") {
                index += 1
            }
            Button("INCR 2") {
                index += 2
            }
            Button("DECR") {
                index -= 1
            }
            Button("DECR 2") {
                index -= 2
            }
            Toggle("Show", isOn: $allow)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .border(Color.red)
    }
}

struct RestrictedPagingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RestrictedPagingViewPreview()
    }
}
```