# Disable Tab View Swipe to Change Page in SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, swipe-gesture, swiftui-tabview

I am using a **tab view** in my SwiftUI app. I want to **disable** its **swipe** to left and write to **move** to other pages. I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524458/swiftui-tabview-pagetabviewstyle-prevent-changing-tab) and also checked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168014/swiftui-2-0-tabview-disable-swipe-to-change-page/63170431#63170431), but none of them works. They are using

> .gesture(DragGesture())

which is disabling the **left** swipe. I want to **disable both** left and right swipe.

I also tried:

> .disabled(true)

which is disabling the whole view. There are buttons on my view to perform some tasks. This disabled them too.

My code is:

```
@State var selectedIndex = 0

var body: some View {

 TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                
                FirstView().tag(0).gesture(DragGesture())
                
                SecondView().tag(1).gesture(DragGesture())
                
                ThirdView().tag(2).gesture(DragGesture())
                
            }.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
```

My **FirstView** code is:

```
func firstView() -> some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
     
            HStack {
                
                Text("Is this a live claim?")
                    .font(.custom(InterFont.bold.rawValue, size: 24))
                
                Spacer()
                
            }.padding()
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            BlueButton(title: "Continue") {
                
               print("pressed")
            }.padding()
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
    }
```

My **SecondView** code is:

```
func secondView() -> some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            HStack {
                Text("Detail of the incident")
                    .font(.custom(InterFont.bold.rawValue, size: 24))
                
                Text("(Optional)")
                    .font(.custom(InterFont.regular.rawValue, size: 14))
                
            }.padding()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                Text("Detail of the incident")
                    .font(.custom(InterFont.regular.rawValue, size: 16))
                
                
                Spacer()
                
                BlueButton(title: "Continue", action: {
                    print("continue pressed")
                })
                
            }.padding()
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
    }
```

My **ThirdView** code is:

```
func thirdView() -> some View {
        
            
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                
                    VStack(spacing: -10) {
                        HStack{
                            
                            Text("Call Police Crime Number")
                                .font(.custom(InterFont.bold.rawValue, size: 14))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("101")
                                .font(.custom(InterFont.bold.rawValue, size: 14))
                                .underline()
                        }.padding()
                            
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    BlueButton(title: "Continue") {
                        
                            print("continue pressed")
                        
                    }.padding()
                 
                }.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
                
            }
```

[image: simulator]

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Show your tab views (or simplified demo for debug), because when I use instead just colors (.red, .green, .blue) then swipe is blocked in both directions. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5. So I assume your issue is due to some conflicts with specific views.

Comment: @Asperi I tried it with colors and it is working, but when I use my views. this is not working. I am attaching a video in my question

Comment: I do believe you :) but video will not help to debug - if you want help you need to provide your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the issue is because your views are transparent, so gesture is ignored due to failed hit testing.

The fix is to make it hit-testable explicitly with `.contentShape` modifier.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                
    FirstView().tag(0)
      .contentShape(Rectangle()).gesture(DragGesture())  // << here !!
    
    SecondView().tag(1)
      .contentShape(Rectangle()).gesture(DragGesture())
    
    ThirdView().tag(2)
      .contentShape(Rectangle()).gesture(DragGesture())

}.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

Comment: This works fine but there is an issue. I have a **button** at the **bottom** of every view, and when I tried to swipe from that button, the view is swiping. Is there any way to stop that too

Comment: Well you can do it actually. If you have button at the bottom you can just use .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture()) instead of .gesture(DragGesture()) combined with .contentShape(Rectangle())

Comment: This does not work. See issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72962447/disable-to-change-page-on-swipe-of-tab-view-in-swiftui