# Disable swipe on TabView while editing (swiftui)

Tags: swiftui, gesture, swipe-gesture, swiftui-tabview

I'm trying to disable the possibility to swipe a TabView in swiftui while a variable (Bool) is set to true but I must miss something very simple. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168014/swiftui-2-0-tabview-disable-swipe-to-change-page) as well as many other posts saying the same but when I run a test it doesn't prevent the swipe for me.

I have a simple test code:

```
struct TabViewTest: View {
@State var editing: Bool = false
var numbers:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { index in
            Button ("Hello, World \(index)!") {
                editing = !editing
                print("Btn \(index) changed editing to \(editing)")
            }
            .gesture(editing ? DragGesture() : nil)
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
}
```

}

Yet when running this I still can swipe no matter if the "editing" variable is true or false.

Here is the log from pressing the button on each Tab:

> Btn 1 changed editing to true
>
> Btn 2 changed editing to false
>
> Btn 3 changed editing to true
>
> Btn 4 changed editing to false
>
> Btn 5 changed editing to true
>
> Btn 6 changed editing to false

What am I missing? everything I find about this offer the same solution yet I'm not able to implement it ... I must miss something basic ...

I have this on the simulator with IOS 16 if this would make a difference.

Edit: it look like this is an issue others face but have not found a solution to yet, I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72962447/disable-to-change-page-on-swipe-of-tab-view-in-swiftui).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524458/swiftui-tabview-pagetabviewstyle-prevent-changing-tab).

The issue is: any view that has an "**onTapGesture**" will ignore "**.gesture(...)**".

The solution is to use "**.simulataneousGesture(...)**" instead to ensure the gesture is capture and handled by both view/modifier.

It worked perfectly in my case after changing it. *The only exception is for 2 finger drag gesture*.

In my case the following code worked:

```
 ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { index in
        Button ("Hello, World \(index)!") {
            editing = !editing
            print("Btn \(index) changed editing to \(editing)")
        }
        .simulataneousGesture(editing ? DragGesture() : nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a `DragGesture` to prevent `TabView` from seeing the drag is good, but you need the `DragGesture` to apply to the whole screen, not just to the button.

```
struct TabLocker: View {
    let pages = Array(1...10)
    @State var locked = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(pages, id: \.self) { page in
                ZStack {
                    // Any Color expands to take as much room as possible,
                    // so it will fill the screen.
                    // Color.clear is invisible so it won't affect the page appearance.
                    // But because it's invisible, SwiftUI doesn't allow it
                    // to receive touches by default.
                    // The .contentShape(Rectangle()) allows it to receive touches.
                    Color.clear
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(locked ? DragGesture() : nil)
                    VStack {
                        Text("Page \(page)")
                        Toggle("Locked", isOn: $locked)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I tried it but the issue remain.  I just found a solution using "simultaneousGesture" though. the issue is that Button has a onTapGesture and this seems to cause problems except if "simultaneousGesture" is used. I found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524458/swiftui-tabview-pagetabviewstyle-prevent-changing-tab